# A totally geodesic triangulation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, triangulations

Let $M$ be a compact orientable $n$ dimensional Riemannian manifold.

Is there a triangulation of $M$ such that every $k$ dimensional face of each simplex is a totally geodesic submanifold, $\forall k \;\;1\leq k \leq n$?

Comment: I don't think so. Even totally geodesic subsurfaces are really rare. For example, if you take a compact quotient of NIL or SOL, I don't believe that there is such a triangulation. related : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18108/must-a-surface-obtained-by-exponentiating-a-plane-in-a-tangent-space-of-a-riemann and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54635/geodesic-2-dimensional-submanifolds-of-a-riemannian-manifold

Answer (score 2):

For surfaces, see

MR1151746 Colin de Verdière, Yves. Comment rendre géodésique une triangulation d'une surface?  Enseign. Math. (2) 37 (1991), no. 3-4, 201–212.